# jQuery manipulating java Hashmap

Tags: java, jquery, dom, servlets, hashmap

Can we use Jquery to manipulate Hashmap directly or i sud manipulate only the DOM data . I have a complex scenario where i need to change the java objects(basically HashMap ) from jquery get Request and get the response and print that in the jsp. User can send number of request and get seperate response from servlet based on request and display the data.
after every request i have to put the map in session and than in another request i get the same in session and do the updates and put it back in session.

1. JqueryGet(parameter) to Java.
2. Updating Hashmap according to parameter.
3. Putting hashmap in session . ( session.setAttribute("map",map))
4. sending response back to Jsp in jquery and print results in jsp.
5. Than another request send to Java .
6. it will get the map from session session.getAttribute("map",map) and than update the map based on new request .
7. Put the map again in session and so on....Than i have a submit button finally which will show the new data on the page and then update the server.

Is this the right approach? My functionality is working fine as of now in Dev environment. But i am worried whether i should use DOM. if i will use DOM it will be very complex since i have to manipulate much values of Hashmap based on request.

Here is the jquery code which is sending some string and array parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=portalContext.createTemplateProcessURI()%>'
    +'?s1='+ $("#networkBox1").val()+'&box1=Box1&tick=add&val1='+ allvs+'&s2='+ $("#networkBox2").val()+'&box2=Box2&val2='+ allvs,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {                      
        Processbox(data);   // This function displaying the result.
    } 
});
```

Comment: jquery or javascript cannot manipulate java map or object.. all they get is string out of it... you need to put them in a map in javascript before you do some computation on it.

Comment: i am passing the string via jquery to my servlet and than manipulating the Java map and hence i think it is possible to manipulate the Java map...after manipualting i am gaian converting my map into the strings in my servlte and sending the response back .